# Finish input to array before printing all

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I am trying to do input to an array until it is full and after that print the entire array. But I cannot get the loop to run until the array is full and after that print all.

Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    String[] course = new String [2]; //creating array
    int [] grade = new int [2];

    System.out.println("Input coursename and grade: ");

    for (int i = 0; i < course.length; i++){
            course[i] = input.next();
            grade [i] = input.nextInt();

    if (i == course.length)
        break;

    //System.out.println("\nHow do you want to order course and grade?");
    //System.out.print("   1 - Ascending?\n"
    //               + "   2 - Decending?\n");

    //System.out.println("Name and grade is " + course[i] + " " + grade[i]);
       System.out.println(Arrays.toString(course)+(grade));

    }

  }
}
```

How can get the loop to run and then jump to the print statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the variable `i` in the loop can never be equal to `course.length` because the loop runs only until `i < course.length`. So the `if` block is redundant anyway.

The printing statement should be AFTER the `for` block, otherwise you'd be printing the array in each iteration.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    String[] course = new String [2]; //creating array
    int [] grade = new int [2];

    System.out.println("Input coursename and grade: ");

    for (int i = 0; i < course.length; i++) {
        course[i] = input.next();
        grade [i] = input.nextInt();
    }

   System.out.println(Arrays.toString(course)+(grade));
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This does the job. But then I get an prette funny print: [ip, er][I@5dccce3c It only prints the course not the grades. I tried with this instead "System.out.println("Name and grade is " + course[i] + " " + grade[i]);" but then my IDE tells me "cannot find variable i"

Comment: You should print like this: System.out.println(Arrays.toString(course) + ", " + Arrays.toString(grade));

Comment: That's because the variable "i" is visible only within the "for" block, not outside of it. So yours "System.out.println("Name and grade is " + course[i] + " " + grade[i]);" could be placed BEFORE the "}" bracket so it will print the course and grade in each iteration of the "for" loop. Or you can print the whole arrays AFTER the "}" bracked like I suggested.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. But If I want the print to be like: course grade, course1 grade1, course2 grade2. Can that be done as well?

Comment: Sure, just place this BEFORE the "}" bracket: System.out.println("Course " + course[i] + " Grade " + grade[i]);

Answer (score 0):

There should be a `}` after `grade [i] = input.nextInt();`.
And the following `if` is not necessary at all.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the loop would do the job if it was closed after the two assignment statements. The check afterwards isn't useful and could be removed.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        String[] course = new String[2]; // creating array
        int[] grade = new int[2];

        System.out.println("Input coursename and grade: ");

        for (int i = 0; i < course.length; i++) {
            course[i] = input.next();
            grade[i] = input.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(course) + (grade));

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`if (i == course.length)` is unnecesery because when `i == length` then for loop finish working and for-loop-body doesn't call so remove this line and put instead of it close loop `"}"`

Next is printing your array. Change the last line to:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(course) + Arrays.toString((grade)));
```